# extract substring at defined position

Tags: php, string, performance, parsing

I have a html string and I want to extract a certain sub string as plain text that always starts at a defined position, how do I do this best?

the html looks like:

```
<table class="views-table cols-4"><thead><tr><th class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
            Title          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
            Unit price          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-quantity">
            Quantity          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
            Total          </th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
             "Sweet Heart" Package    (SPA02)          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
            135.00  CAD          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-quantity">
            1          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
            135.00  CAD          </td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

and I want to extract the string `"Sweet Heart" Package    (SPA02)`, how do I do this most efficiently?

Thanks

**EDIT 1**
I took Vinie's solution for a spin and just added the echo before the call to `get_string()` but for some reason strpos() is not able to find `$start` within `$string` which is odd as I printed them both to the screen and I can see, the contents are definitely within the string!

```
<?php
function get_string($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = 0;
    $pos = strpos($string, $start, $pos);
    if ($pos === false)
    { // Zero is not exactly equal to false...
        return $found;
    }
    $pos += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $pos)-$pos;
    $found = substr($string, $pos, $len);
    return $found;
}

$str='<table class="views-table cols-4"><thead><tr><th class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
        Title          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
        Unit price          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-quantity">
        Quantity          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
        Total          </th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
         "Sweet Heart" Package    (SPA02)          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
        135.00  CAD          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-quantity">
        1          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
 135.00  CAD          </td>
</tr></tbody></table>';

 $str=strtr($str,array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;"));
 echo get_string($str,'class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">&lt;td    class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">','&lt;/td>');
?>
```

Comment: how would you like to parse it ? It's form ?

Comment: @cerr do you want to remove it or what?

Comment: @acontell I would like to extract it, remove all the rest....

Comment: @cerr so you know the position, do you know the length of the string as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to extract your string.

```
function get_string($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = 0;
    $pos = strpos($string, $start, $pos);
    if ($pos === false)
    { // Zero is not exactly equal to false...
        return $found;
    }
    $pos += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $pos)-$pos;
    $found = substr($string, $pos, $len);
    return $found;
}

$str='<table class="views-table cols-4"><thead><tr><th class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
        Title          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
        Unit price          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-quantity">
        Quantity          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
        Total          </th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
         "Sweet Heart" Package    (SPA02)          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
        135.00  CAD          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-quantity">
        1          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
 135.00  CAD          </td>
</tr></tbody></table>';

 $str=strtr($str,array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;"));//echo $str;
 get_string($str,'class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">&lt;td    class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">','&lt;/td>');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this for some reason doesn't seem to work correctly. See **EDIT 1** above